# Flatten hierarchy of clients

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with 4 clients hierarchies, each in a column (4 columns). I would like to generate a table from this with in one column all unique codes from the 4 hierarchy columns and another column with the correspondent code from the first column.

As in the example below:

from this:

```
   Tier1    Tier2   Tier3   Tier4
  --------------------------------
   1230     1100    1000    1000
   1230     1100    1001    1001
                            1002
   1230     1100    1222    1003
                            1004
```

To this:

```
Unique  Tier4
---------------
1000    1000
1001    1001
1002    1002
1003    1003
1222    1003
1100    1000
1100    1001
1100    1003
1230    1000
1230    1001
1230    1002
1004    1004
```

Comment: @ram: how do you do to insert tables like this? thanks for the edit!

Comment: You can make something fixed-width by putting 4 spaces at the start of the line.

Comment: Why is `1002` in the results?  Shouldn't it be missing because it doesn't have any other tiers?

Comment: `the correspondent code from the first column` by column you mean row?

Comment: @BaconBits: fixed 104, was 1004. If it does not have hierarchy I need it to be repeated (as 1002 in 3rd line of results)

Comment: I need the lower tier (4) with all its possible combinations... on 1st row all unique values and on the second column the lower tier of which it correspond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want, but I think something like this should do:

```
SELECT Tier1, Tier4 FROM Table WHERE Tier1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Tier2, Tier4 FROM Table WHERE Tier2 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Tier3, Tier4 FROM Table WHERE Tier3 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Tier4, Tier4 FROM Table WHERE Tier1 IS NULL AND Tier2 IS NULL AND Tier3 IS NULL
```

If the missing values aren't `NULL`, you'll need to modify the code, of course.

Edit adding: Note also that the last query there is only adding `Tier4, Tier4` to the results if that field has nothing else in the heirarchy, because that's how you phrased your comment.  Looking again, though, I see `1003, 1003` in your results.  You may actually want `SELECT Tier4, Tier4 FROM Table` as the last line of the query instead of what I have.

---

You can insert this into an existing table with:

```
INSERT INTO ExistingTable (Field1, Field2)
SELECT Tier1, Tier4 FROM Table WHERE Tier1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Tier2, Tier4 FROM Table WHERE Tier2 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Tier3, Tier4 FROM Table WHERE Tier3 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Tier4, Tier4 FROM Table WHERE Tier1 IS NULL AND Tier2 IS NULL AND Tier3 IS NULL
```

Otherwise I'd create the table separately and then insert.  You may also just want a `VIEW` instead.  It's not clear what you're using this for.  You may instead want to create it as a VIEW, however, if you intend to keep the old table.

Comment: Your final `where` clause is overly complicated.

Comment: how would I make this an make table query? adding insert into hierarchy is not working...

Comment: @GordonLinoff He said he wants `Tier4` listed in both fields when it has no other tiers.  I'm assuming that otherwise it will work.  You have an alternative?